# Multivariable limit help

Tags: multivariable-calculus

To me this limit should be $0$, simply by squeezing with $2xy^2-y$ as upper bound and $y-2xy^2$ as lower bound.

Is WolframAlpha wrong, am I using WolframAlpha wrong, or am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: Tell it that $x$ and $y$ shall be real. It says "may depend on […] path in **complex** space".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the squeeze theorem is correct over $\mathbb{R}^2$.

WolframAlpha is showing a non existent limit for complex $x$ and $y$.

Hovering the cursor over the result yields expected value for real variables (maybe some sort of UI bug).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$|f (x,y)|\leq |y|(|2xy \sin (\frac {1}{xy})|+|cos (\frac {1}{xy})|)\leq |1+2xy||y|\longrightarrow 0$$ for $(x,y)\longrightarrow (0,0) $